# Add a fade in to offsetTop

Tags: jquery, offset

This should be fairly simple, but jquery is not my strong suit.

I am looking to add a simple fade in/out when the css class is added to the element, which occurs after the offset. I know of fadein/fadeout class but I'm not sure how to implement it in this occasion.

[Fidde here](http://jsfiddle.net/j32t2/1)

```
jQuery(function(){
  var menuOffset = jQuery('.header-bar')[0].offsetTop;
  jQuery(document).bind('ready scroll',function() {
    var docScroll = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
    if(docScroll >= menuOffset) {
      jQuery('#navigationtop').addClass('fixed').css('width',jQuery('#masthead').width());
    } else {
      jQuery('#navigationtop').removeClass('fixed').removeAttr("width");
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle?  Also, use $ whenever you can instead of jQuery!

Comment: ill make it. Have to use $ because its on wordpress

Comment: @IrvinZhan fiddle added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

http://jsfiddle.net/j32t2/4/

CSS - hide it initially

```
.fixed { 
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 700;
    top:0;
    display: none;
}
```

JS - fades it in if it is not already there

```
jQuery(function(){
  var menuOffset = jQuery('.header-bar')[0].offsetTop;
  jQuery(document).bind('ready scroll',function() {
    var docScroll = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
    if(docScroll >= menuOffset) {
        if( !jQuery('#navigationtop').hasClass('fixed')) {
            jQuery('#navigationtop').addClass('fixed docked').css('width',jQuery('#masthead').width()).fadeOut(0).fadeIn(1000); 
        }
    } else {
        if( jQuery('#navigationtop').hasClass('docked') ) {
            jQuery('#navigationtop').removeClass('docked');
            jQuery('#navigationtop').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                $(this).removeClass('fixed').removeAttr("width").show();
            });
        }
    }
   });
});
```

Please note I did not add a fadeOut. The check for class fixed is needed or it's going to constantly fadeIn. For some docs, http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ and http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: Hi @huangism. Thanks for the answer. Works well, just a shame it doesn't fade out. :)

Comment: I've added a fadeout, you can check the fiddle and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You simply needed to hide it by default.  What I like to do is use [`.stop(true, true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop whatever animations that may currently be running.  Then I use [`.hide(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to instantly remove the menu. All that's left is to add the class and fade it in via [`.fadeIn('slow')`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/).

## ***jQuery***

---

```
jQuery(function () {
    var menuOffset = jQuery('.header-bar')[0].offsetTop;
    jQuery(document).bind('ready scroll', function () {
        var docScroll = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
        if (docScroll >= menuOffset) {
            jQuery('#navigationtop')
                .stop(true, true)
                .hide(0)
                .addClass('fixed')
                .fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            jQuery('#navigationtop')
                .removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

## ***CSS***

---

```
#navigationtop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 700;
    top: 0;
}
```

## ***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JW65s/)***

Comment: hi. I like your answer but when after the menu appears and I scroll, it flickers as it is reloaded

Comment: It fades both ways when I run the example

Comment: This does not have the check for the docked class which is why it keeps fading in if you keep scrolling down